# ZF with "double powersets", is there a set with the same size as ℝ?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If you replace the axiom of the powerset, with one guaranteeing the existence of double powersets only ... roughly speaking, what changes?

---

Here's the axiom of power set in ZF**, written out in first order logic with a binary predicate $\in$.

$$ \forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff \forall w (w \in z \implies w \in x) $$

equivalently, using $\mathcal{P}$ and $=$

$$ \forall x \exists y \left[ x = \mathcal{P}(x) \right]$$

If, instead of this axiom, you took the putative *double powerset axiom*

$$ \forall x \exists y (y = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(x)) $$

written out fully it's

$$ \forall x \forall y \forall z . x \in y \iff (\exists v . (\forall u . u \in z \implies u \in v) \land (\forall w . w \in v \implies w \in x) ) $$

from

$$ \forall x \forall y \forall z . (x \in y \iff z \subseteq \circ \subseteq x ) $$

would you *still be able to construct all the cardinals in the $\beth$ hierarchy*?*

I think it's the case that, if any of the $\beth$ cardinals are inaccessible after swapping out the powerset axiom, it's $\beth_1, \beth_3, \beth_5, \cdots$.

So, concretely, is a set with cardinality $|ℝ|$ ($\beth_1$) guaranteed to be there after the swapping out the powerset axiom?

* I'm just thinking about a set theory as collections of theorems/tautologies in first order logic with $\in$ as the sole non-logical connective/predicate thing. $=$ and $\mathcal{P}$, where they appear, are intended as syntactic sugar only. I think you can write down probes in first-order logic to test for the presence of sets of a particular cardinality. If you can't, I'm not sure what the appropriate way to extend the system is. Targeting such a cardinality is what I mean by "constructing". I'm also not commenting on whether there are non-finite cardinalities outside the $\beth$ hierarchy... I don't know enough to make a comment about them, so I'm explicitly only talking about the $\beth$ hierarchy.

** I don't know what would happen here if we take the axiom of choice. A solution that needs choice would also be interesting.

Comment: $=$ isn't just syntactic sugar, it's a logical symbol - like the Boolean connectives, the quantifiers, parentheses, and variables. *(Early treatments of first-order logic didn't necessarily include equality, but it has become universal.)*

Comment: How should you write $=$ when you mean it to be an abbreviation of $\forall w. w \in x \iff w \in y$? I was taking the axiom of equality (I meant extensionality) as the definition of $=$ . Sounds like doing that is rare and weird.

Comment: *(Do you mean ["extensionality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality) rather than "equality"?)* Extensionality is *not* the definition of "$=$" - what it does is let us conclude $x=y$ merely by knowing $\forall w(w\in x\iff w\in y)$. Equality is built directly into the syntax and semantics of first-order logic. This becomes less mysterious when you leave set theory for a second and think about some other theory - say, the theory of [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) - where there is no obvious understanding of what equality "is" besides "sameness."

Comment: On this note, one half of extensionality is trivial *(precisely, one half of extensionality is [**true in every $\{\in\}$-structure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Semantics))*: that $x=y$ implies $\forall w(w\in x\iff w\in y)$. It's the other direction which has actual mathematical content *(that is, which is true in some, but not all, $\{\in\}$-structures)*.This is a bit off-topic, though, and might be better addressed in a subsequent question. Sorry to derail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that double-powerset gives you back powerset, without using choice: [Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) lets you get something "morally equivalent" to the powerset, and [Replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) goes the rest of the way.

In more detail, suppose $y$ is the double powerset of $x$ - that is, suppose that the elements of $y$ are precisely the sets of subsets of $x$. Then by Separation, the subclass $$z=\{a\in y: \vert a\vert=1\}$$ is a set. Replacement tells us that the class $$z'=\{a: \{a\}\in z\}$$ is a set *(the map $\{a\}\mapsto a$ being definable)*, but $z'$ is just the powerset of $x$.

---

EDIT: As Henning Makholm points out below, we can avoid  replacement and separation *both* by simply noting that $$\bigcup P(P(x))=P(x).$$

Comment: Is it okay to use a map that sends a singleton set to its element? I thought the map had to be total. (We can just send non-singleton sets to the empty set or something ... I'm just wondering whether you technically need to do that or not)

Comment: @GregoryNisbet To apply Replacement, the map just has to be total *on its domain*, which in this case is $z$ - since every element of $z$ has exactly one element, we're good to go.

Comment: You don't even need Replacement; $\bigcup \mathcal{PP}(X)$ will do.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Derp - and that gets rid of separation, too! Edited.